# Getting very low/ wrong accuracy from RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning

I am currently using RandomizedSearchCV to optimize my hyper-parameters. However the reported scores of each iteration is very low. When I then evaluate the highest scoring candidate I get very high accuracy (0.97), while the RandomizedSearchCV reports something much lower (0.32).

```
search = clf_rand_search.fit(x_traintest, y_traintest)
print(search.score(x_validation,y_validation))
0.32

print(accuracy_score(y_validation.flatten(), search.predict(x_validation).flatten()))
0.9798260869565217
```

My input and output are both 2-D matrix with (100,9) and (100,230) shape for the train/test data. With lower samples for the validation data.

Should I format my data differently for the RandomizedSearchCV?

Input features first two are normalised and the last one-hot encoded.
[image]

Output classification 0 or 1 for 230 nodes.
[image]

```
clf = MLPClassifier(solver = 'adam', 
                max_iter=9999,
                alpha=1e-5
                )

hidden_layers = 8
neurons = list(range(10,210,5))

m = [0]*(hidden_layers*len(neurons))

for i in range(1,hidden_layers+1):
    for idx,i2 in enumerate(neurons):
        m[((i-1)*len(neurons)) + (idx)] = [neurons[idx]]*i

param_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes':   m,
    'activation':           ['identity', 'logistic', 'tanh', 'relu'],
    'learning_rate':        ['constant','invscaling','adaptive'],
    'learning_rate_init':   np.arange(1e-4,0.1+1e-4,1e-4)
    }

clf_rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_space, n_iter=10,
                                        scoring="accuracy", verbose=True, cv=2,
                                        n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: is your RandomizedSearchCV using accuracy as a score? You know that accuracy is not the best metric for imbalanced datasets... If perhaps, the RandomizedSearchCV is using other than accuracy as its score the results could make sense, If you didn't provide any specific score to the RandomizedSearchCV  it will use the score defined in the estimator

Comment: It is using accuracy as a score yes. I will add the setup of the RandomizedSearchCV

Comment: Are you computing the accuracy with the one-hot econded? If so, when you do the flatten, a lot of zeros will be the same in the predictions and the ground truth. Compute the accuracy with the labels before the one-hot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE AFTER EXCHANGING COMMENTS**

You might be facing issues with the computation of the accuracy

- I think the MLP with the log-loss can work well with your output data. Your output data is a vector $(N, 230)$ with $N$ the number of samples, with only 1s or 0s. This data is indeed a one-hot encoded vectors with multiple 1s.
- You are computing the accuracy by flattening the predictions and comparing them elemt-wise ($N*230$ elemetns),
- For computing the accuracy, I guess if the classifier is not comparing the one-hot vectors (ground truths and predictions) element wise , but comparing if they re the same for each one of the $N$ samples.  Think that if only one element of the 230 onte-hot encoded is missclassified in one sample, this accuracy will drop by $1/$N$*100$ %. If accuracy is computed element-wise, the drop in the accuracy will be $1/(230*N)*100$ %...
- Try to update your accuracy computation assingning a 1 only if each predicted (230, 1) vector of each sample is equal to its (230,1) ground truth vector.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE COMMENTS**

I guess you are experimeting problems with your data...

Your data does not seem to be a binary classification problem, for binary classification your data should have the following dimensions:

- Input: $(N, K)$
- Output: $(N, 1)$ or $(N, 2)$ if is one-hot encoded.

With $N$ the number of sample of the split, $K$ the dimension of the feature input space

If your output data is of size

$(N, D)$,

then it could be a regression problem that maps a feature space of $K$ to $D$. Yout MLP should try to mimmic a function.

$f'(X): K \to D$

For regression problems you must use other metrics, like MAE or MSE

You can treat the problem from various perspectives (just some ideas).

- as a masking/segmentation problem in 1D (making an analogy with mask segmentation for 2D images...)
- A Bayesian approach could work well also. You can try to estimate the posterior probability of parameter of the Binomial distribution which models the nodes being 1 or 0 (posterior) from your data (likelihood)... and then update your posterior distribution with new data so that you can have updated and more accurate credible intervals. Obviouslly you may thing about if a Binomial distribution models fine your data (i.e. independancy, etc...) Maybe other probability distribution works better

Thge following example works well. I know it does not answer the question (I'm just trying to help), but at least, we can see with an example that `RandomizedSearchCV` should give the same score as the `accuracy_score` with your code for a binary classification problem with a MLP

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scipy.stats import uniform
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
clf = MLPClassifier(solver = 'adam', 
                max_iter=9999,
                alpha=1e-5
                )

hidden_layers = 2
neurons = list(range(10,210,5))

m = [0]*(hidden_layers*len(neurons))

for i in range(1,hidden_layers+1):
    for idx,i2 in enumerate(neurons):
        m[((i-1)*len(neurons)) + (idx)] = [neurons[idx]]*i

param_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes':   m,
    'activation':           ['identity', 'logistic', 'tanh', 'relu'],
    'learning_rate':        ['constant','invscaling','adaptive'],
    'learning_rate_init':   np.arange(1e-4,0.1+1e-4,1e-4)
    }

clf_rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_space, n_iter=2,
                                        scoring="accuracy", verbose=True, cv=2,
                                        n_jobs=-1)

search = clf_rand_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(search.score(X_test,y_test))


print(accuracy_score(y_test.flatten(), search.predict(X_test).flatten()))
```

Comment: Only one input feature is one-hot encoded. The output is a classification between 0 and 1 as can be seen from the last image. So accuracy will not be measured on one-hot encoded labels.

Comment: Then, for each (100, 9) input matrix you are classifying a (100, 230) matrix whose elements are 0 or 1.

Comment: RandomizedSearchCV sees each row as a seperate sample right? The whole training dataset has 100 samples. Should I format my input and output differently then?

Comment: Then you have 100 samples with 9 features? What is the output size for a single sample, 230? If so, what kind of problem are you solving? If it is binary classification and your samples are vectors o 9 features, your data should have a size of (100, 9) for input and (100,1) for output or (100,2) if it is one-hot encoded... I don't understand the 230 output size if it is binary classification...

Comment: Please add a description of the problem, input feature space dimension and output dimension, specifying what dimension refers to number of samples

Comment: Thank you for your answer and trying to help me out. I think we are nearing the problem here. I will detail my whole problem. I am trying to classify flooding for manholes in an area so 0 is no flood and 1 flood. So there are 230 manholes that I classify as 0 no flood or 1 flood. The input features are features of a precipitation event. Hope this gives some better understanding of my dataset. Your example works fine but it only classifies one output, while I have multiple. I hope my terminology is good, I am fairly new in the data science space.

Comment: Then, you are facing the problem in the wrong way... it is not a binary classification problem... It is indeed binary for each single node, but if you are trying to predict all nodes at the same time with a MLP, is no binary... If you add a link to your data, a better solution could be got

Comment: I can't share my data unfortunately. I see now, the MLP classifier thought I was one-hot encoding. Multiple output classification is not possible then? Then I should probably train an MLP for each node. I have already done MLP regression which works.

Comment: I think the MLP with the log-loss can work well with yout output data. If yout output data (100, 230) is indeed one-hot encoded with multiples 1s. For computing the accuracy, I guess if the classifier is not comparing the one-hot vector element wise , but comparing if for ech dataset sample, the vectors are equal. Try to update your accuracy computation assingn a 1 only if each predicted (230,1) vector of each sample is equal to its (230,1) ground truth vector

Comment: Think that if only one element of the 230 changes in one sample, for 100 samples the accuracy will drop 1%. If accuracy is computed element-wise, the drop in the accuracy will be 1/(230*100)...

Comment: Thanks a lot! log loss seems to work well with the data.